# bounded derivative and connected subsets

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function such that its derivative is a bounded function. Prove that, if $E \subset \Bbb R$ is connected, then $f[E]$ is connected.

My attempt: As the function has derivative, then is continuous. Also, I know continuous image of connected subsets is connected. But in my attempt, I am not using the hypothesis of bounded derivative.

I would really appreciate your help to identify what is wrong in my reasoning and what is the best way to prove this.

Comment: You should be right though.

Comment: You are correct, and the question is weird.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. So, are you telling me there is no way to use that hypothesis? It could be discarded?

Comment: @JuanC Yes, as long as you don't discard the hypothesis that $f$ is continuous.